# Cannot import conftest.py on Windows

Tags: python, importerror, pytest

I'm quite new to pytest and creating packages (modules) in general. I had a few tests written in pytest which worked well until I refactored scripts structure. This was actually neccessary, because there was many scripts and it was quite chaotic for orientation. The current directory structure looks this way:

```
C:\Users\local\workspace
         .+---tools
             +---base
                 +---__init__.py
                 +---conftest.py
                 +---script1.py
                 +---script2.py
             +---misc
                 +---__init__.py
                 +---run.py
             +---__init__.py
```

`script1.py` and `script2.py` include some classes and special classes for testing. I was told that `conftest.py` should be located in the same folder as top-level test files, so I put it into `base` directory.

I run pytest from `run.py` by the following way:

```
pytest_args = workspace + "/tools/base/script1.py "
pytest_args += workspace + "/tools/base/script2.py"
pytest.main(pytest_args)
```

where `workspace` contains `c:/Users/local/workspace`. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\_pytest\config.py", line 543, in importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\py\_path\local.py", line 660, in pyimport
     raise self.ImportMismatchError(modname, modfile, self)
 ImportMismatchError: ('tools.base.conftest', 'c:/Users/local/workspace\\jenkins\\tools\\base\\conftest.py', local('c:\\Users\\wokspace\\tools\\base\\conftest.py'))
 ERROR: could not load c:\Users\local\workspace\tools\base\conftest.py
```

I really don't know, how to fix this. Everything worked fine when all scripts were in the same folder (and without `__init__.py`). Other scripts work fine (I mean with depencies, where some script needs a module from other directory), just pytest fails on this.

Weird is that on Linux distributions, this works fine. I guess there is a problem with windows paths, which seems to be a real problem for pytest.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this please?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you remove the file `base\__init__.py`?

Comment: Actually, this is not possible, because base has to be a package, for it contains, as the name says, basic classes which are used by other scripts. I would rather think about moving testing classes (from script1.py and script2.py) into another directory (without __init__.py) along with conftest.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem, and what eventually fixed it was deleting all my `__pycache__` directories and `.pyc` files.